# Excel VBA Delete and Shift Up cells but only in a certain range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am making a calendar for my university courses. 
Please take a look at the Screenshot. The number in bold are the days.

[Screenshot](https://ibb.co/mEsjFe)

I need to clean the different days of the week from blank cells but without misalign the following week.

In the screenshot, the numbers in bold must remain in the same row but all the content of the week must be shifted up in order to compact all together.

The result should be:

[Result:](https://ibb.co/hPMx1K)

I need a suggestion for doing this for a week and then I will replicate it for all the weeks of the calendar.

hope it is clear
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion for you, I think you can delete and shift Up cells in a certain range [test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQu52.png)

You could try the steps below:

1.Get the last count of rows in certain range and the last value for each column.

2.Copy the last value of each column in the last row then delete it.

3.Paste the last value of each column into the last row.

Hope it helps you.

Thanks,

Yuki